# Me not understanding do while loops

Tags: c++, loops

So i tried to make my first console aplication but it came to a bit of a bummer since i dont understand how a do while loop works

```
#include <iostream>

int balance = 100;
int pay = 30;
int awnser;

// Variables for the awnsers
int withdrawal;
int a = 1;


int main() {
    do {
        std::cout << "\n Whats the action you wanna do? \n 1 = Check balance \n 2 = Withdraw money \n 3 = Deposit money \n 4 = Check transaction history \n 5 = Exit \n";
        std::cout << " ";
        std::cin >> awnser;

        if (awnser == 1) {
            std::cout << balance << " Euros\n \n";
        }

        if (awnser == 2) {
            std::cout << "How much do you wanna with draw?\n";
            std::cin >> withdrawal;
            if (withdrawal > balance)
                std::cout << "You dont have that much money.\n \n";
            else {

                std::cout << "Your current balance is: " << balance - withdrawal;

            }

        }

        if (awnser == 3) {
            std::cout << "We know you dont have enymore daam money you beggar so dont even try that\n \n";
        }

        if (awnser == 4) {


        }

        if (awnser == 5) {
            std::cout << "Enter 0 to exit or 1 to go back\n";
            std::cin >> a;
        }
        else if (a == 1) {
            std::cout << "\n";
            return 1;

        }


    } while (a == 1);

}
```

I thought it would get back to the top since no other "if" requierements were met and just give me the "Whats the action you wanna take again" but it just exits out so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend using a debugger. That way you can execute your program 1 line at a time and look at the variables at each step and understand the flow of the execution.

Comment: `else if (a==12) ... return 1;` Is the cause. Also, it's spelled answer.

Comment: `return 1;` in `main()` means end the program.

Comment: If `a==1` return;   this might be the case

Comment: What’s the point of `a`? Also, you might want to use a `switch` instead of `if`s.

Comment: Hello! again since i just started on this site 3 minutes ago probably i dont know how to awnser to you guys directly lol. BUT thanks alot for the awnsers i thought it would not matter if the "return 1;" was there since it was inside a else ifs brackets but the more you know! Again thanks alot

Comment: And to "failure by desing" the point of "a" is to keep the loop running and to modify it to 0 should you want to exit

Comment: @Tuke "_since i just started on this site 3 minutes ago probably i dont know how to awnser to you guys directly_" If you started on this site 3 minutes ago, you should've taken the [tour], and read through [help], **before** trying to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number input isn't one that you check (1 to 5) then you hit:

```
else if (a == 1) {
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

which will enter the `if` (because `a` is 1), print a new line and `return` from `main` ending your run.